# Transform PHP script to a general-case function

Tags: php, function

I have this code that modify date in the way I want, for example, if starting date is 31/01/2000, adding 1 month will return 29/02/2000, then, 31/03/2000.
If date is 30/01/2000 (not last day of the month) it will return 29/02/2000, then 30/03/2000, 30/04/2000 and so on.

I want to transfirm that code in a general case function, to be able to add 1,3,6,12 months, and inside the for loop, to work all corect. 
I would like it to be a function 2 or 3 arguments, startingDate, duration(nr of iterations), frequency (add 1/3/6/12 months per once).

```
   <?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-28'); // or whatever
#echo $date->format('d')." ".$date->format('t');
$expectedDay = $date->format('d');
$month = $date->format('m');
$year = $date->format('Y');

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d')  . "<br>"; 
    if ($month++ == 12) {
        $year++;
        $month = 1;
    }

    $date->modify("${year}-${month}-1");
    if ($expectedDay > $date->format('t')) {
        $day = $date->format('t');
    } else {
        $day = $expectedDay;    
    }
    $date->modify("${year}-${month}-${day}");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whelp, there's an extremely easy function for this in PHP nowadays.

first, you get a timestamp instead of a datetime:

`$timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();`

### Now, just use [strtotime](https://www.php.net/strtotime) to add onto the date.

`strtotime("+1 month", $myTimestamp);`

You can change the +1 into anything you want, so you just throw the amount in the string and voila; a dynamic way of adding them!

**however**, since you want to do +30 days instead of a natural month, you're better off just adding 30 days to the timestamp, like so:

`$timestamp = $timestamp + (3600 * 24 * 30); //s per h * h per d * d`

So, you'd end up with something like this:

```
function calculateTime($startingDate, $iterations, $frequency){
    $timeStamp = strtotime($startingDate);//if you expect a string date
    $timeToAdd = (3600 * 24 * 30) * $frequency; //30 days * frequency
    $return = array();
    $return[] = date('Y-m-d', $timeStamp); //Original date
    $previousDate = $timeStamp; //Original date  for now
    for($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++){
        $newDate = $previousDate + (3600 * 24 * 30);
        $return[] = date('Y-m-d', $newDate);
        $previousDate = $newDate;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

And then for the rendering part:

```
//Let's render this stuff
$dates = calculateTime('24-08-2017', 25, 3);
foreach($dates as $date){
    echo "$date</br>";
}
```

### If you'd like to do it with full months, something like this:

```
<?php
function calculateTime($startingDate, $iterations, $frequency){
    $timeStamp = strtotime($startingDate);//if you expect a string date
    $return = array();
    $return[] = date('Y-m-d', $timeStamp); //Original date
    $previousDate = $timeStamp; //Original date  for now
    for($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++){
        $lastDay = false;
        //It's the last day of the month
        if(date('t', $timeStamp) == date('d', $timeStamp)){
            $lastDay = true;
        }        
        if($frequency == 12){
            $newDate = strtotime('+1 year', $previousDate);  
        }
        else{
            if($lastDay){
                $firstDayOfMonth = strtotime(date("01-m-Y", $previousDate));
                $newDate =strtotime("+$frequency month", $firstDayOfMonth);
            }
            else{
                $newDate = strtotime("+$frequency month", $previousDate);
            }
        }
        if($lastDay){
            $return[] = date('Y-m-t', $newDate);
        }
        else{
            $return[] = date('Y-m-d', $newDate);
        }
        $previousDate = $newDate;
    }
    return $return;
}
//Let's render this stuff
$dates = calculateTime('31-01-2000', 25, 1);
foreach($dates as $date){
    echo "$date</br>";
}
```

I hope this helps? :)

If you'd like to see how this works quickly, just paste my code into a [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/). Unfortunately the save function is broken right now.

Comment: Thank you for this help, but it is not what I expect. When I introduce a date of 30 january 2000, frequency 1, it gives me next date of 2th march. But from my rigorous restrictions, it must give me 29feb 2000, then 30 march, 30 april and so on.
If starting date is 31january, it must return 29feb 2000, 31 march, 30 april, 31 may...

Comment: @new_newB1e hmmm... Getting the last day of a month really isn't hard either (`strtotime('last day of next month', $previousDate)`, but then you'd just have to add a differentiation within the function to check if it's the last day of the month, then grab the last day of the next month?

Comment: @new_newB1e I have updated the code to include the last day of the month... I'm sorry but I can't really help you on this regard unless there is a very clear rythm in how you want to add these months. Is there a specific system? If it's just static dates, your only choice would be to do a `switch` case or a lot of if statements.

Comment: Edited code miss the February in many cases
If I introduce 30/01/2000 or 31/01//2000, next date would be 30/31 of March :/

Comment: @new_newB1e I have added an exception for the `$lastDay` case. Now, if it's the last day of a month, it will first head back to the first day of the month, then add a month and only then it will revert back to the last day again before saving it. Now it doesn't skip february anymore :)